# Facebook App Request On Mobile

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, apprequests

I have a Facebook JS SDK apprequest button on my website..! Here is the code

```
var receiverUserIds = FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'apprequests',
        title: campaignTitle,
        message: campaignMessage,
        data: { productId : campaignId }
    },
    function (receiverUserIds)
    {
    }
```

It works fine on normal browsers (laptop and PC) but for mobile browsers, the app request get stuck on loading... I tried both on iphone and andriod..! Here is the screen shot

[image: Screen shot of app request on mobile browser]

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting lots of reports of this as well for my app Fish Wrangler.  I can't reproduce it, so I haven't been able to debug it yet.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.techques.com/question/1-10181714/Facebook-apprequests-Stuck-Loading

Comment: It's being looked into at Facebook.. marked high priority.
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/232968666865788

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing same issue with Facebook (Mobile) since last week.

FB.ui() is setting **X-Frame-Options: DENY**, which then stop loading the contents in the iFrame via the JS SDK. I tried modifying header in IIS on my side to no avail.

I then try to open the app requests using URL Redirect method i.e. as follow:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id=XXXXXXXXX&message=Test&redirect_uri=http://example.com is working fine when viewed on Desktop

As soon as I try to view it on mobile devices (iPhone, Android) or using fake user agent in Chrome, it fails.

https://m.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id=XXXXXXXXX&message=Test&redirect_uri=http://example.com

casper123, you can try above and see if it works for you (probably not).

I think something changed for Facebook App Requests mobile recently. Looks like we need to wait for official Facebook response on this issue.

Thanks

Fahad

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Facebook fix this issue. See this bug that @joe-faron mentioned.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/232968666865788

We have implemented a different solution for our problem which was to do a redirect to Facebook web URL (https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?..) that then changed automatically to m.facebook URL (whatever that is). It worked for us and we are sticking with it as this worked out much cleaner solution for us.

Thanks

Fahad